# Replace values by the most present value

Tags: r

```
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "c")
Value <- c("blue", "blue", "green", "red", "orange", NA)
df <- tibble(ID, Value)
```

I have to group by the ID, keep the value of Value which is the most repeated
If the values are equal `(ID == "B")`, I choose the first value

The value variable should look like :

```
Value_output <- c("blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", NA)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/8583393) and then do `... %>% mutate(Value = Mode(Value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the `Mode` by group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   arrange(ID, is.na(Value)) %>% # in case to keep non- NA elements for a tie
   mutate(Value_output = Mode(Value))
```

where

```
 Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

#### data

```
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "c", "c")
Value <- c("blue", "blue", "green", "red", "orange", NA, "yellow")
df <- tibble(ID, Value)
```

Comment: if I add the row `c , yellow` to my dataframe, and I want too keep yellow and not the NA value for the c ID how to solve that  ?

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko  Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `data.table` package (count `Value` by `ID`).

```
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "c")
Value <- c("blue", "blue", "green", "red", "orange", NA)

library(data.table)
foo <- data.table(ID, Value)
setkey(foo, ID)
foo[foo[, .N, .(ID, Value)][order(N, decreasing = TRUE)][, .(Value = Value[1]), ID]]$i.Value
[1] "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "red"  NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: If you had akrun's helper function `data.table` solution could be reduced to: `df[, Value := Mode(Value), ID]`

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

```
lot <- aggregate(
  Value ~ ID, 
  df, 
  function(x) names(sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE))[1]
)
df$Value <- lot[match(df$ID, lot$ID), "Value"]
df
  ID    Value 
  <chr> <chr> 
1 A     blue  
2 A     blue  
3 A     blue  
4 B     orange
5 B     orange
6 c     NA
```